# Refresh window on url change - AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, url

Well I've a webpage let it be the destination written in AngularJS which is accessed from another webpage(not AngularJS) let it be the source.

So from source if I click a button it opens the destination webpage in a new window.

Source will have a drop down box based on which the destination webpage's URL is constructed.

For example, let the drop-down values be Apple, Mango and Banana.
If apple is selected and the button is clicked the destination webpage is opened with a url

http://localhost:10000/webapp/hello1/#?id=apple

based on the id the UI will be painted.

so for mango and banana the url will be like

http://localhost:10000/webapp/hello1/#?id=mango

http://localhost:10000/webapp/hello1/#?id=banana

The problem is now when apple is selected and button is clicked the destination webpage is opened. And when the destination is not closed and when I select mango and click the button the destination webpages url is changed but the page is not refreshed.

So what is problem here? Is it because of AngularJS or should I include any code so that the page gets refreshed automatically when the URL changes?

Comment: Could you provide some code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since # is used to differentiate the path and query parameters in the URL (AngularJS format) and when the query parameter values are changed after the page is loaded, the page doesn't refresh automatically.

It can be fixed using the below code where the hashchange event fires when a window's hash changes.

```
window.onhashchange = function() {
    window.location.reload();
};
```

Answer (score 0):

if your using ui-router then use this

```
ui-sref="dashboard" ui-sref-opts="{reload: true}"
```